# Allocating memory for uint8_t array

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, uint8t

Using `C++`, I'm trying to read from a file that looks like this:

```
111111100100000000001101
100011100000000000000000
111111000100000000101001
001011110100000000000011
001111000100000000000110
```

Each line represents 3 bytes, and I want to store the whole file in memory using an array of `uint8_t`.

I wrote this code, and in the while loop I just pick up the first byte of each line for simplicity:

```
    uint8_t * buffer = new uint8_t[lSize];
    memset(buffer, 0, lSize);
    ifstream file(argv[1]);
    string str;
    int i=0;
    while(getline(file, str)){
        string byte = str.substr(0,8);
        bitset<8> bitsaddress(byte);
        int number = bitsaddress.to_ulong();
        buffer[i]=number;
        cout << buffer[i]<<endl;
        i++;
    }
```

But the output on the shell is something like this:

```
-
�
�
'

-
e
N
k
```

If I print the variable `number` instead of `buffer[i]` I have the correct behaviour.

I don't understand why this happens, can someone explain?

Comment: So you want to split this thing up to 3 bytes per row, and store those?

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *printable* characters are a subset of all the values represented by a byte. Everything from 32 to 126 is represented visually by something that you would recognize as a character, but the rest of the values are not. Some of the other values do things that you would recognize, like adding a newline or causing a beep, but depending upon how your terminal is interpreting everything else, you are going to get different forms of gibberish on the terminal.

For the sake of debugging, try printing all of your results as integers or hex strings.

Comment: you are right! if I print buffer[i] casting it to (int) I have the correct value! tks

Comment: You should not cast these values to `int`, since that's a signed integer type, and the values you're casting to `int` are unsigned. Explicitly casting signed integers to unsigned or vice-versa is a bad idea. Cast them to `uint` or `uintX_t` (where X is 16, 32, or 64) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
ifstream myFile("myFile");
assert(myFile.is_open()); // #include <cassert>

string str;
vector<uint8_t> vec;
int count = 0;

while (getline(myFile, str)) {
    uint8_t tmp = 0;
    for (const auto& c : str) {
        count++;
        tmp <<= 0x1;
        tmp |= (c - '0');
        if (count >= 8) {
            vec.push_back(tmp);
            tmp     = 0;
            count   = 0;
        }
    }
}

myFile.close();

for (const auto& v : vec) cout << (uint32_t)v << endl;
```